# WP8 root frame change

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Am trying to change root frame in code behind:

```
    // Do not add any additional code to this method
    private void CompleteInitializePhoneApplication(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        // Set the root visual to allow the application to render
        if (RootVisual != RootFrame)
        {
            RootVisual = RootFrame; // here or somewhere before ...               
        }
```

... I need to change the root frame (but no in manifest).
Has anyone any idea? Answers or tips are very appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to change the RootFrame?

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: ok. I have a start page in manifest...that's right, but after first app launch I need to set an other page like a start page

Answer (score 1):

You can use another frame when app is just initializing. Just modify the `InitializePhoneApplication()` method in `App.xaml.cs`:

```
private void InitializePhoneApplication()
{
    if (phoneApplicationInitialized)
        return;

    // Instead of creating a PhoneApplicationFrame, use your own
    RootFrame = new YourSuperCoolFrame();
    RootFrame.Navigated += CompleteInitializePhoneApplication;

    ... // rest of the original code
}
```